# How to change an unlisted video to public

Tags: ios, youtube, gdata-api

i have added a video as unlisted to youtube using-

```
[entry addAccessControl:[GDataYouTubeAccessControl accessControlWithAction:@"list" permission:@"denied"]];
```

how can i make the video public some time later? thank you